# Parsing out all the flash cookies being used on a site

Tags: c#, .net, flash, cookies, selenium

I was wondering whether it is possible to capture the names (and any other avail info) of all the flash/lso cookies being used by a particular web page. I'm using Selenium atm to parse all Http Cookies, but the the same methods can't be used to detect flash cookies. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with a network traffic sniffer (in browser like Firebug net tab, HttpFox, LiveHttpHeaders, ieHttpHeaders, or external sniffer like Wireshark, Fiddler).

Those should be able to show you the cookies returned by server and cookies sent by browser client (supposedly including the Flash content) via the HTTP request/response headers.